# How to match systemd-boot and init font

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, systemd-boot

I'd like to have systemd-boot font matched with init process (systemd).
My system is Arch Linux.
I attach two screenshot;

one of systemd-boot,
[image: init]
one from init process.
[image: systemd-boot]

*Is there a way to match fonts?*

Comment: Which one do you want to change?

Comment: I'd like to change both because I like none of them, thus if I can change only one, doesn't matter which